# How to select a row in data GridView and populate another gridview?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

This might be a repeat question but i didn't find any solution that helps me. So asking again separately. I would appreciate if anyone provide me any solutions.

I Would like to show a data gridview and just select any of the rows of that data and another gridview would be populated using that selected row value.

```
     <div>
        <table align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="950px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </div>

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GetAccounts()
End Sub

Protected Sub GetAccounts()
    Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim objAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim objDataSet As DataSet
    sqlString = "SELECT * FROM hanger"

    objCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlString, conn)
    objAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(objCommand)
    objDataSet = New DataSet()
    objAdapter.Fill(objDataSet)
    GridView1.DataSource = objDataSet
    GridView1.DataBind()

    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then : conn.Close() : End If
End Sub
```

Comment: where is the code that attempts to do what you are asking?

Comment: @Plutonix I'm doing this for the first time so no clue where to start! Sorry about that.

Comment: OnSelectRowCommand get currently selected row details, create table with those details and set this table as DataSource for second grid

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm giving you a very generic solution, you can get the idea from here and implement your own code.

**ASP Markup**

> The Dummy LinkButton is used, so that the ASP.Net __doPostBack JavaScript function is rendered as we will require it for making the Row Clickable by raising PostBack.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Code Behind**

> **Page Load Event Handler**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(2) {New DataColumn("Id"), New DataColumn("Name"), New DataColumn("Country")})
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

> **OnRowDataBound Event Handler Of GridView1**

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.Attributes("style") = "cursor:pointer"
    End If
End Sub
```

> **OnSelectedIndexChanged Event Handler Of GridView1**

```
Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim index As Integer = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex
    Dim name As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text
    Dim country As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text

    //Extract the Row Identifier And Bind The Second GridView Here
End Sub
```